# Identify which service listens for notifications but doesn't consume them

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6

I have a huge database where, in some places, we use Postgres notifications. We noticed that the queue size is increasing. The way we check is executing this simple command: `select pg_notification_queue_usage();`.

When it reaches 100% then all messages are gone. The problem I have is that I don't know who listens to notifications and what channels we have there. I identified only two services that listen for those notifications but it seems that's not the case.

My task is to find other places where we use notifications (consume or produce) to find the root cause. How can I do it?

The only thing I found about it is the query `select pg_notification_queue_usage();` but it seems that Postgres doesn't provide other useful functions related to this feature.

I did some experiments regarding it. I launched a local Postgres instance and started publishing notifications there. Everything worked as expected. When I did it once again but without actual consuming notifications, the queue size started to grow. That's what I expected, tho.

Then, I restarted the process and the queue size dropped to 0. That's exactly what the docs say about it.

> A session's listen registrations are automatically cleared when the session ends.

On the production, we did exactly the same - we restarted known services but the notification queue didn't drop to 0 as we expected.

It means, there's something else listening to one of the channels but it doesn't consume it or does it too slow.

Is there any way of identifying such listeners?

Comment: That should mean that there is a hung backend that doesn't receive interrupts. Probably in state `active`.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: Postgres 9.4 is [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)  you should plan an upgrade as soon as possible.

Comment: yeah, we have plan to upgrade it soon but the problem still exists :)

Comment: Can you see any hung backends with state `active` in `pg_stat_activity`?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe unfortunately, no. When I execute `select * from pg_stat_activity where query like '%LISTEN %';` command I can find only one record but there should be at least two (two services use two different channels). What may cause it?

Comment: You don't have to look for backends where the query is `LISTEN`. Look for backends where the process is stuck - either has a weird state in `ps`, or is spinning in an endless loop (bug).